# Error in adding schema location showing "Downloading external file disable" but i already enabled Artifact Javadoc

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-mvc

[Here i use spring-t x both x m l ns and x s i but still it showing "Downloading external resources is disabled."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLYAI.png)

I already go to Preferences>>Maven and check box Artifact Javadoc but still not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlxhM.png)